# Difference between combination of AND and OR when placed inside the parentheses vs when placed stand alone in a conditional statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting different number of results when I have the script like the following:

```
select count(distinct(t1.ticketid)),t1.TicketStatus from ticket as t1
inner join Timepoint as t2 on t1.TicketID=t2. ticketid
where 
    t2.BuilderAnalystID=10 and t1.SubmissionDT >='04-01-2018'  AND
      (t1.TicketBuildStatusID<>12 OR
       t1.TicketBuildStatusID<>11 OR 
       t1.TicketBuildStatusID<>10
      )
```

And when I use it like this:

```
 select count(distinct(t1.ticketid)),t1.TicketStatus from ticket as t1
    inner join Timepoint as t2 on t1.TicketID=t2. ticketid
    where 
        t2.BuilderAnalystID=10 and t1.SubmissionDT >='04-01-2018'  AND
        t1.TicketBuildStatusID<>12 AND
        t1.TicketBuildStatusID<>11 AND 
        t1.TicketBuildStatusID<>10
```

Can someone tell me why there is a difference, to me the logic is the same!
Thanks,

Comment: Those 2 queries won't produce different results. Please provide sample data (in the form of DDL AND DML statements) that we can use your query against that **replicates** the problem.

Comment: On a different note, why not replace the last 3 clauses with `t1.TicketBuildStatusID NOT IN (10,11,12)`?

Comment: It would be weird if they produce different results.

Comment: @Larnu; I needed to put OR. I updated the logic.

Comment: In your first query those three ORed conditions are useless and should be removed by the optimizer. Any NOT NULL value is not equal to one of those values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, it won't matter because you have all AND clauses.  That said, you need to be aware of precedence (ie order of operations) where `NOT` comes before `AND`, `AND` comes before `OR` and so on.

So just like 3 + 3 x 0 means 3 + (3 x 0), A or B and C means A or (B and C), even if that's not what you meant.

So in cases where you have mixed AND and OR clauses, it matters a lot.

Consider this example:

```
select *
from A, B
where A.id = B.id and A.family_code = 'ABC' or A.family_code = 'DEF'
```

It's horrible code, I admit, but for illustrative purposes, bear with me.

You may have meant this:

```
select *
from A, B
where A.id = B.id and (A.family_code = 'ABC' or A.family_code = 'DEF')
```

but you said this:

```
select *
from A, B
where (A.id = B.id and A.family_code = 'ABC') or A.family_code = 'DEF'
```

Which in the construct above completely blows away your join, resulting in a cartesian product for all cases where the family code is DEF.

So bottom line: when you mix clauses (AND, OR, NOT), it's best to use parentheses to be explicit about what you mean, even when it's not necessary.

Food for thought.

-- EDIT --

The question was changed after I wrote this so that the queries were NOT the same (ands were changed to ors).

Hopefully my explanation still helps.

Comment: The question was edited to have `OR` instead of all `AND` for those reading this thinking it makes no sense

Answer (score 2):

After the edited to your question there will now be a difference.

```
t2.BuilderAnalystID=10 and t1.SubmissionDT >='04-01-2018'  AND
      (t1.TicketBuildStatusID<>12 OR
       t1.TicketBuildStatusID<>11 OR 
       t1.TicketBuildStatusID<>10
      )
```

This query will return values where `t1.TicketBuildStatusID` is 10, 11 and 12.  It states that it should not be 10 (so 11 and 12), or not be 11 (so 10 and 11), or not be 12 (so 10 and 11).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *those* queries will produce different results. In fact, the first query will return every value of `TicketBuildStatusID` unless it has a value of `NULL`.

When `TicketBuildStatusID` has a value or `12` it **doesn't** have a value of `11` or `12` so the expression `(t1.TicketBuildStatusID<>12 OR t1.TicketBuildStatusID<>11 OR t1.TicketBuildStatusID<>10)`, is true. If it has a value of `11`, then the same applies again, and for every other possible value, apart from `NULL` (as `{expression}<>NULL` = `NULL` which is not true).

Answer (score 1):

when you do this

```
 AND
      (t1.TicketBuildStatusID<>12 OR
       t1.TicketBuildStatusID<>11 OR 
       t1.TicketBuildStatusID<>10)
```

you are basically doing no filter because any of the condition evaluated to true will make all the condition true e.i.

```
true AND (true or false or false) = true
```

when you do this all conditions should match like status should not be 12,11,10

```
 AND
        t1.TicketBuildStatusID<>12 AND
        t1.TicketBuildStatusID<>11 AND 
        t1.TicketBuildStatusID<>10
```

Answer (score 0):

`OR` isn't the logic that you want.  Because if x = 12, then it is not 11.  So, all values match `x <> 12 and x <> 11`.

So, just simply the logic and use `not in`:

```
select count(distinct t1.ticketid), t1.TicketStatus
from ticket t1 inner join
     Timepoint t2
     on t1.TicketID = t2.ticketid
where t2.BuilderAnalystID = 10 and
      t1.SubmissionDT >= '2018-04-01' and
      t1.TicketBuildStatusID not in (12, 11, 10)
```

Notes:

- `distinct` is not a function, so there is no need to place the following expression in parentheses.
- Use standard date formats.  Either 'YYYYMMDD' or 'YYYY-M-DD'.